# Restart appdomain for each test

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, xunit.net

I realize it may sound like an odd request, and it certainly will not do wonders for test performance, but it's critical that I get a new AppDomain for the start of each unit test.

Currently I'm using xUnit and Resharper as the test runner. But I'm willing to change if there's a different framework that would yield the behaviour that I need.

Answer (score 3):

The xunit resharper runner doesn't have this kind of functionality, and I don't know any test framework that does this out of the box. If you need each test to run in a new AppDomain, I'd write it so that each test created a new AppDomain and ran some custom code in there.

You could probably use some of xunit's features to make this a little easier - the [`BeforeAfterTestAttribute`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/Sdk/BeforeAfterTestAttribute.cs) allows you to run code before and after, or you could pass in a fixture that provides functionality to setup/teardown the AppDomain.